# How to store byte[] from Android Camera onPictureTaken method within application for later use

Tags: android, image, camera

I am writing a larger Android application and I use the camera within the app.  All I want to do with the camera is have the user take a picture, then start a new activity to show that image and allow the user to decide if they want to keep the image or not.  I am having the hardest time figuring out how to simply store the byte[] data from the onPictureTaken method so that I can display it to the user in the next activity.  I have tried many different routes and none of them have worked.  The last thing I tried was creating a globalsettings class that extends the Application class and creating a byte[] field within it to store the byte[] from the camera so that I could use it within another activity, but my global variable is still not getting set.  My CameraActivity code is shown below:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity
{
    CameraPreview Preview;
    Intent intent;
    byte[] image;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cameralayout);
        Preview = new CameraPreview(this);
        ((FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.uxfmlayPreview)).addView(Preview);
        intent = new Intent(this, PostCaptureActivity.class);
    }

    public void uxbtnCaptureSnap_Click(View v)
    {
        Preview.DeviceCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        Preview.DeviceCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,   jpegCallback);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void uxbtnCaptureExit_Click(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ExploreMenuActivity.class);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback()
    {
    public void onShutter() {}
    };

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() 
    {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {}
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() 
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            ((GlobalSettings)getApplication()).setGlobalImage(data);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;

        }
    };
}
```

Here is my code from my PostCaptureActivity onCreate() method where I attempt to convert and set the image as the source for an imageview:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.postcapturelayout);
    SnapShot = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.uximgSnapshot));
    if(((GlobalSettings)this.getApplication()).getGlobalImage() != null)
    {
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(((GlobalSettings)this.getApplication()).getGlobalImage(), 0, ((GlobalSettings)this.getApplication()).getGlobalImage().length);
        SnapShot.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Oops! Picture cannot be saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This post no longer requires an answer.  I figured out what was wrong.  Once I actually debugged the app on my device I realized that I was getting a java.lang.outOfMemory in the log.  To fix this I used a quick algorithm to find the smallest supported picture size specific to the device that the app is running on and then set that as the picture size for the camera.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Intent:

```
intent = new Intent(this, PostCaptureActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image", data);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Put this inside the `onPictureTaken` method.